# looping pairs of jQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

in python, there is a way to loop 2 small equal size list as pairs of element easily:

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5]
 b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
 for x, y in zip(a, b):
    #do something
```

what is the similar way in javascript/jquery; 
for eg. i have 2 lists:

```
var a = $(".class1");
var b = $(".class2");
```

rather than having to write:

```
for(var i = 0;i<a.length;i++) {
    var x = a[i];
    var y = b[i];        
}
```

Comment: why is that for loop not ok? You don't have much choice in JS. Either that or `forEach(function(el,index,array){})` but you'll still have to use the `index` to keep track on the current iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short way

> No there is nothing like this in Javascript to do thing like this.

You can use `forEach` and `for-loop` but you need to same thing what you did in above example (using index).

I thing you need to understand that `JavaScript` has own advantage in some filed and python has own.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the enhanced `for` loop useful in javascript. Then create a custom zip method.

```
function zip(val1, val2, callback) {
    if(val1.length !== val2.length)
        return;
    for(var i in a) {
        callback.call(this, i, val1, val2)
    }
}

zip(["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], function(index, val1, val2) {
    console.log(val1[index] + " "  + val2[index]);
});
```